# Программа для поиска файлов по маске с самоудалением

Tags: bat, кириллица

Имеется следующий код программы:

```
    #include "iostream"//i/o
#include <windows.h> //FindFirst(Next)File
#include <shlobj.h>  //Диалог выбора файла
#include <stdio.h>   //sprintf
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
//#include <local.h>
using namespace std;
//Руссификация
ostream& operator<<(ostream &stream, char* s){
        for(char* ps=s; *ps; ps++){
                if(*ps=='ё')
                        stream<<char(241);
                else if(*ps=='Ё')
                        stream<<char(240);
                else if(*ps>=-64 && *ps<=-17)                   
                        stream<<char(*ps+64+128);
                else if(*ps<0)
                        stream<<char(*ps+64+176);
                else
                        stream<<*ps;
        }
        return stream;
}
void del(); 
char * SelectFile(HWND hWnd);
bool   IsFile(LPCTSTR sPath);
//Поиск файла в каталоге sPath по маске sMask и наличии текста sFind в нём
bool   FindFile(LPCTSTR sPath, LPCTSTR sMask, LPCTSTR sFind);
//Поиск текста sFind в файле sPath
bool   FindText(LPCTSTR sPath, LPCTSTR sFind);
bool   IsStrEqualMask(LPCTSTR s, LPCTSTR sFind);

int main()
{
    char ch;
    char szFilePath[MAX_PATH];
    char szFindMask[MAX_PATH];
    char szFindText[1024];//Для вводе текста для поиска есть хоть каки*то ограничения
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
int n;
bool Flag;
DWORD dwDrivesMap = GetLogicalDrives();
strcpy(szFindMask, ".docx");
int k;
    char dd[4];
    DWORD dr = GetLogicalDrives();

    for( int i = 0; i < 26; i++ )
    {
        k = ((dr>>i)&0x00000001);
        if( k == 1 ) 
        {
            dd[0] =  char(65+i); dd[1] = ':'; dd[2] = '\\'; dd[3] = 0;
            strcpy(szFilePath, dd);
            FindFile(szFilePath, szFindMask, szFindText);
        }
    }

    system("pause");
del();

    return 0;
}

bool IsFile(LPCTSTR sPath)
{
    bool bFile = false;
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile
        (
            sPath, 
            GENERIC_READ,
            FILE_SHARE_READ,
            NULL, 
            OPEN_EXISTING, 
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            NULL
        );
     if(hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
     {
         CloseHandle(hFile);
         bFile = true;
     }               
     return bFile;
}

bool FindFile(LPCTSTR sPath, LPCTSTR sMask, LPCTSTR sFind)
{
    bool bFind = false;
    char sDir[MAX_PATH];
    WIN32_FIND_DATA pDATA;
    strcat(strcpy(pDATA.cFileName,sPath),"\\*.*");
    HANDLE hFile = FindFirstFile(pDATA.cFileName,&pDATA);
    ofstream endfile("search result.txt", ios::app);
    if(hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            if(strcmp(pDATA.cFileName,".")  == 0 ||
               strcmp(pDATA.cFileName,"..") == 0)
               continue;
            else
            {
                sprintf(sDir,"%s\\%s",sPath, pDATA.cFileName);
                if(pDATA.dwFileAttributes != FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
                {
                    if(IsStrEqualMask(pDATA.cFileName, sMask))
                    //if(FindText(sDir, sFind))
                    {
                        endfile<<"Найден файл :["<<sDir<<"]\r\n";
                        bFind = true;
                        //break;//Если поиск успешен, сразу прекращаем поиск
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Нашли подкаталог - ныряем в него
                    if((bFind = FindFile(sDir, sMask, sFind)))
                    {
                        //break;//Если поиск успешен, сразу прекращаем поиск
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        while(FindNextFile(hFile,&pDATA));
    }
    endfile.close();
    return bFind;
}

bool FindText(LPCTSTR sPath, LPCTSTR sFind)
{
    long sLen;
    char * str;
    bool bRet = false;
    FILE * f = fopen(sPath,"r");
    if(f)
    {
        fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);
        sLen = ftell(f);
        fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
        if((str = new char[sLen + 1]))
        {
            fread(str,sLen,1,f);
            str[sLen] = '\0';
        }
        fclose(f);
        if(str)
        {
            //Решил не изобретать велосипед а воспользуваться уже имеющейся функцией
            bRet = IsStrEqualMask(str, sFind);
            delete [] str;
        }
    }
    return bRet;
}

bool IsStrEqualMask(LPCTSTR s, LPCTSTR sFind)
{
    bool bEqual = true;
    //шаблон может содержать ' ' '\\' ',' '.' '*'
    char delim[] = " \\,.*";
    char * sMask = new char[strlen(sFind) + 1];
    strcpy(sMask,sFind);

    char * buf = strtok(sMask,delim);
    while(buf)
    {
        if(!strstr(s,buf))
        {
            bEqual = false;
            break;
        }
        buf = strtok(NULL,delim);
     }
     delete [] sMask;
     return bEqual;
}

void del()
{
    ofstream bat("del.bat", ios::app);
    bat<<"@Echo off "<<endl;
    //bat<<"@cd с:windows "<<endl;
    bat<<"del Poisk_failov.exe /q /F "<<endl;
    bat<<"del %0 /q /F "<<endl;
    bat.close();
    //system("pause");
    system("start del.bat");
}
```

И собственно возникли две проблемы. Первая - пути и названия файлов на кириллице в конечном текстовом файле отображаются некорректно, например так:
Найден файл :[D:\jvgjhg\ђҐдҐа в ў‚Љ\Ќ ЈЈа­пЄ - ў­да бвагЄвга  ўЈ¤ЄаЁвЁе Є«озЈў.docx]
Что делать не знаю... Проблема явно в кодировках и локализациях, но ничего не помогает.
Вторая проблема - бат-файл, он не удаляет программу как он должен, пишет, что "отказано в доступе", хотя себя удаляет нормально, и еще нормально работает если программа работает с несистемными дисками(в выложенном коде - она работает со всеми дисками системы). В ХР бат-файл вроде нормально работает, а в 7-ке проблема.

Comment: Windows: windows-1251
Unix: UTF-8

Comment: Для начала: все ваши строки должны быть даже не `wchar_t[]`, а `std::wstring`. Это настолько очевидно в 2013-м году, что уже даже не смешно.

Во-вторых, запущенная программа не может быть удалена. Если процесс чужой, найдите его и завершите (если, конечно, хватит прав на это). Если это ваш процесс, скопируйтесь в `%TEMP%` и запустите процесс оттуда.

Comment: решил проблему с кодировками гениально - закомментил тот кусок в начале, который перегружает вывод в файл, и все работает.
Осталась проблема с БАТником - в семерке отказывает в доступе, в ХРшке работает норм, файл-экзешник удаляется. Еще бы знать как скрыть окно командной строки, а то ЕХО ОФФ не помогает